# page width in bootstrap responsive design on iphone

Tags: iphone, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a bootstrap responsive design working well on a wide range of browsers, but the page width is limited on iPhone. I have already added the viewport meta tag:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

And it does not seem to help. The site is here: http://themenuengine.com. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

Around line 780 of `bootstrap-responsive.css`:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
```

Override that padding with `0` and it will be full-width.

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, That definitely helps Sara. The main problem am having is the width of the panels (what I call pages). They are set to 100% width, but are being limited. I assume this is some intentional responsive behavior, but I can't quite figure it out. It looks like this is only real pronounced when you are viewing the site vertically.

Comment: Are you referring to the gray on either side of the `.panel` divs? If so, that's due to `padding: 10px !important` on line 164 of `style.css`. Try using the Chrome Web Inspector or Firebug to find the culprit in situations like this (right click on extra space -> Inspect Element -> look at applied styles). You can selectively enable/disable styles and watch the results in real time.

Comment: what i am referring to is specifically on the iphone. the page width is limited to 480px (or something like that) when its vertical. i was trying to figure out how to override this without much luck so far.

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have anything built in to detect iPhone vs other hardware; it's entirely based on screen size & media queries. You can achieve the same results by resizing your browser window to the screen width of an iPhone.

Comment: try not do use !important. Just have 
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        body {
            padding-right: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }
    }

later on in a stylesheet located after bootstrap-responsive.css is loaded in the DOM and you're golden. By adding in !important in your responsive stylesheets will create a nightmare later on, worse than when we had stylesheets without !important

Comment: yeah, i always made a point of avoiding them, but i'm using the php less compiler and i've been having trouble with the cascade in certain places. i think the bottom line here is i am converting a standard design; its probably time to start thinking mobile from the start.